# Removing item from the api react hooks

Tags: reactjs

```
function DataProfile({ weather, setWeather }) {
  const { id } = weather;
  const cityName = weather.city.name;
  const countryName = weather.city.country;
  const minTemp = weather.list[0].main.temp_min;
 

  const removeCity = (itemId) => {
    setWeather(weather.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="list">
        <button onClick={removeCity} >
          x
        </button>
        <p>
          {cityName} {countryName}
        </p>
        <p>MaxTemp : {maxTemp}</p>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hey, I'm trying to remove city from coming API, but I get error that filter is not a function. Anyone has idea why I get this error. I have initialized weather with useState([]).

Comment: Please add the error that you are getting in the question ,I without it nobody can help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error just means that you're trying to use `.filter` on a variable that is not an array.

Maybe the **weather** variable is just an object, and to remove it's content it would be as simple as re-setting it's state to an empty object like this:

```
setWeather({});
```

I'm assuming you did `const [setWeather, weather] = useState({})` before and then assigned a value to it with `setWeather()`, and wish to revert it back to an empty object.

In this case, the **removeCity** function would look like this:

```
const removeCity = () => {
  setWeather({});
};
```

I think this works for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

3 things

1. You should look at Object methods (Object.fromEntries, Object.entries, Object.keys...) to use functions like filter on objects
2. If setWeather is from a useState(), your usage is wrong, you should use it according to the doc, by  getting the previous state like this: `setWeather((prevState) => ...)`

> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:
> https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

3. Finally your code seems wrong, if weather is an object with an id `const { id } = weather;`, I don't think there is anything to filter based on an id there